# Socket.IO console.log not firing correctly

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

With the following code snippet, the console.log both explicitly defined and within the callback only fire when connections are made from 127.0.0.1.

```
    service.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
        console.log("Incoming Socket Connection -> ",socket.id);
        if(typeof fn === 'function'){fn(socket);}
    });
```

Any other machines will not fire, but they receive connections and are served pages.  Does NodeJS only show console output with connections from 127.0.0.1?  I am very confused by this, and its making testing very difficult.

Comment: What does your client-side connection code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was pointing to 127.0.0.1, so it was pointing to local instances of socket on other developer's machines. Problem solved.